# java how to convert a string to net.sf.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, couchdb

I get tweets and use org.json.simple api to convert a string to a object.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
Object json = jsonParser.parse(in);
```

and I would like to insert the obj into couchdb using couchdb4j api

```
 Session myDbSession = new Session("localhost",5984)
    Database myCouchDb = myDbSession.getDatabase("db-name");
    Document newdoc = new Document();
    Document newdoc = new Document(JSONObject json);
    myCouchDb.saveDocument(newdoc);
```

The error is:

```
   org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject
```

how to solve this problem or anyone can give a solution to insert a json format string or object into couchdb

Comment: check your imports, make sure you use the library for json parsing properly, that is if you are using json.simple, then it would be better not to use `net.sf.json.JSONObject` object.

Answer (score 4):

As the error said, couchdb may use net.sf.json.JSONObject.

I've found an API in net.sf.json.JSONObject to convert a string to JSON object:

`public static JSONObject fromObject( Object object ) {
      return fromObject( object, new JsonConfig() );
   }`

It's OK with String cause

`else if( object instanceof String ){
         return _fromString( (String) object, jsonConfig );
      }`

This may be help.

Answer (score 1):

To convert String to net.sf.json.JSONObject

```
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with converting from `org.json.simple.Object` to `net.sf.json.JSONObject` why not start with `net.sf.json.JSONObject` in the first place? Using your code...

```
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(in);

Session myDbSession = new Session("localhost",5984)
Database myCouchDb = myDbSession.getDatabase("db-name");
Document newdoc = new Document();
Document newdoc = new Document(json);
myCouchDb.saveDocument(newdoc);
```